# Written Excel VBA to Copy text from one Word document to another Word document - Footer formatting is not retained

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vba, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007

Please help me on the issue. I have successfully copied the content from one word document to another word document. But the footer format is changed after paste the content. Below is my code.

```
Sub CopyFile_Blank()
Dim Word As New Word.Application
Dim WordDoc As New Word.Document
Dim WordDoc1 As New Word.Document
Dim dialogBox As FileDialog
Set dialogBox = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

'Set the display properties - these are optional
'All the settings must be applied before the .Show command

'Do not allow multiple files to be selected
dialogBox.AllowMultiSelect = False

'Set the title of of the DialogBox
dialogBox.Title = "Select a file"

'Show the dialog box and output full file path and file name
If dialogBox.Show = -1 Then
   MsgBox "You selected: " & dialogBox.SelectedItems(1)
End If
    Dest_File = "C:\test\test.docx"
    Doc_Path = Dest_File

Set WordDoc1 = Word.Documents.Open(dialogBox.SelectedItems(1), ReadOnly:=True)
WordDoc1.Range.Copy

Set WordDoc = Word.Documents.Open(Doc_Path, ReadOnly:=True)
WordDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting

WordDoc.ActiveWindow.Visible = True

WordDoc1.Close
End Sub
```